# Trying to figure out why my formula only works in the first row of a sheet that adds new rows automatically

Tags: excel

I am at a loss as to how to address this. My goal is to use the same formula (SUMPRODUCT) to achieve the same result in my long term storage for conditional formatting. Adjusted to reference the appropriate cells on two sheets (so as to make sure nothing breaks when short term is deleted), in theory, my formula should work.
I do know that I can reference one of the sheets used in my current formula as I have already used it for another conditional formatting situation on the same sheet (just without a range so maybe that is why it's not working?).

Over the weekend, I tried to use VBA to accomplish my task.
Today I am asking for help to see where I may have gone wrong in my formula, or if it's a VBA task (if it's VBA I've had no luck in finding what code would work so direction would be appreciated in that case). I know anything, within reason can be done with Excel but I don't know if this one requires VBA or if I can just use a formula similar to the one below.
The formula in question is below and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gchi.jpg) are a few screenshots of what I am referencing. *Picture (1)* shows the type of results I am looking to achieve while the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLbtz.png) shows what is happening along with the range showing correctly.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3),1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X18:$X38)/(SUM($B3:$V3))>0.95
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3),1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X18:$X38)/(SUM($B3:$V3))=0.9
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3),1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X18:$X38)/(SUM($B3:$V3))<0.9
```

**Note**: The error indicator on *Picture (2)* says "The formula in this cell refers to a range that has additional numbers adjacent to it."
In the event that the text under my pictures doesn't show, below is their description/ explanation.
*Picture (1)* Weekly Job Progress (Temporary data erased weekly)
*Picture (2)* Hour Storage (Long term storage for hours, $W3 needs to be highlighted via the results from the formula)
*Picture (3)* Item Storage (Long term storage for daily items completed)

Comment: As it turns out, the cell references in 'Weekly Job Progress' needed to be made absolute for the formula to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the cell references in 'Weekly Job Progress' needed to be made absolute for the formula to work properly as shown below. I got help outside and was able to get it working.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3),1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X$18:$X$38)/(SUM($B3:$V3))>0.95
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3),1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X$18:$X$38)/(SUM($B3:$V3))=0.9
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3),1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X$18:$X$38)/(SUM($B3:$V3))<0.9
```